# Checking whether some object has been already tested

Tags: vim, recursive-datastructures

I have a script that is intended to check whether some value (e.g. option or function argument) matches some model. I want my script to be able to check recursive data structures. So the question is: is there more efficient way then iterating over some list that contains references to already checked Lists and Dictionaries. Example code:

```
function s:AlreadyChecked(arg, checkedlst)
    if type(a:arg)!=type([]) && type(a:arg)!=type({})
        return 0
    endif
    for obj in a:checkedlst
        if a:arg is obj
            return 1
        endif
    endfor
    call add(a:checkedlst, a:arg)
    return 0
endfunction
```

Seeking for a way to sort `checkedlst` (that is to compare references, but not values found by them) or even to use a hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm guessing you've already discovered, Vim doesn't allow List or Dictionary variables to be used as dictionary keys. That means you can't, for example, populate a "checked" dictionary like this:

```
" Unless k is a String, this won't work.
:let checked[k] = 1
```

It also lacks a straightforward way to generate a unique String from a List or Dictionary, so this isn't reliable either:

```
:let checked[ string(k) ] = 1
```

A better approach is to mark the data structures themselves instead of trying to build a hashtable. If you don't mind temporarily making your data structures read-only, one way to do that is to use `:lockvar`:

```
:let someDict = {}
:let someDict['foo'] = [1, 2, 3]
:lockvar 1 someDict
```

That marks `someDict` as read-only. (The `1` limits the locking to the top level of the Dictionary, so nested structures aren't automatically locked.) A variable's lock state can be inspected like this:

```
:echo islocked('someDict')
1

:echo islocked("someDict['foo']")
0

:echo islocked("someDict['foo'][0]")
0
```

Unlocking is just as easy:

```
:unlockvar 1 someDict
```

So now we have a technique for marking individual levels of nested data structures as "checked", a way to query whether or not a particular level is marked, and a way to remove all the marks when we're done. Putting it all together, `AlreadyChecked()` can be modified like so:

```
function! s:AlreadyChecked(arg, checkedlst)

    if type(a:arg)!=type([]) && type(a:arg)!=type({})
        return 0
    endif

    " If this particular List or Dictionary has already been checked, just
    " return true immediately.
    "
    if islocked('a:arg')
        echo "Already checked."
        return 1
    endif

    " Lock the List or Dictionary to mark this item as already
    " checked. Note that only the top level of the List or Dictionary
    " is locked; values are not locked.
    "
    lockvar 1 a:arg

    " Remember everything we've locked, so it can be unlocked once
    " we're done.
    "
    call add(a:checkedlst, a:arg)

    return 0

endfunction
```

Once you're done checking, just remove all the locks:

```
for obj in a:checkedlst
    unlockvar 1 obj
endfor
```

Hope this helps. It's a hackish abuse of the locking facility, but perhaps it will do what you need.

Comment: Thanks, if I combine your answer with `deepcopy` (that will purge locks and make data independent of its source), then it should work fine.

Comment: But you have a mistakes: `let someDict{'foo'}=...` will create a variable `someDictfoo`, you should change it either to `someDict.foo` or to `someDict["foo"]`, see `:h curly-braces-names`.

Comment: Ah, good catch. This is what comes from switching too quickly between Perl and Vimscript. :-)  I've corrected the examples to use the proper syntax. Glad the answer was still useful.